# Question related to two closely separated signals that need to be analyzed by a spectrum analyzer

Tags: rf, spectrum-analyzer

> **Question**
>
> The settings of a spectrum analyzer are given as following:
>
> - Center Frequency = 1.89 GHz, RBW = 10 kHz, VBW = 10 kHz and Span = 50MHz.
> - The Reference Level is set to -20 dBm and detector mode is Positive Peak.
> - The RBW selectivity is \$1:15\$ for \$RBW_{-3 dB}\$ : \$RBW_{-60 dB}\$.
>
> If we are studying a CW signal of 1890 MHz with -23 dBm output power, then
>
> a) How close to your studied signal may a signal of the same amplitude be 
>   and still be measurable? Explain the conditions for close-in signals to be resolved.
>
> b) How close-in signals with power level 50 dB below your studied signal can you detect?

---

**My Attempt**

Is my reasoning making sense to you?

a) "Thumb rule" (I guess?) for *equally* powered CW Carriers, they should be at least \$RBW_{-3 dB}\$ far apart in order to resolve and measure them.

b) For *unequal* powered signals CW Carriers (have power difference of 50 dBc), they should be at least \$RBW_{-50 dB}\$ far apart in order to resolve and measure them.

Comment: Depends on the weighting applied: Hamming, Kaiser, Blackburn, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function